# Quais as diferenças entre "type=button" e "type=submit" em um input?

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Eu tenho um código JavaScript simples para adicionar uma *string* a uma lista `ul`:

## JS:

```
function init() {
    var botao = document.getElementById("addButton");
    botao.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

function handleButtonClick() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
    var songName = textInput.value;
    if (songName == "") {
        alert("Por favor, adicione um pergunta");
    } else {
       //alert("Adicionando a música " + SongName);
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = songName;
        var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

## HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="songTextInput" size="40" placeholder="Nome da música">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Adicionar música">
</form>
<ul id="playlist">
</ul>
```

O problema é: Quando eu defino meu input com `type=button`, este *javascript* funciona, mas quando eu defino como `type=submit`, ele roda legal até a primeira condição ou com o alerta da segunda condição, mas não adiciona a string na lista.

Alguém sabe porque isto acontece?

Comment: Da algum erro no console?

Comment: Parece que ele está recarregando a página, não? O submit submete o formulário (ou seja, navega para a URL especificada como `action` do form, ou para a própria página).

Answer (score 4):

O **`type='submit'`** tem um comportamento especial, quando pressionado o formulário será enviado — a menos que você previna isso com Javascript. Já o **`type='button'`**, como o tipo sugere é somente um botão que por padrão não tem nenhuma funcionalidade — o qual você pode adicionar com algum *script*.

Já o problema no seu código é que a função **`init`** — responsável por atribuir o evento de clique ao botão — nunca é executada, logo, quando o botão é pressionado ele mantém sua funcionalidade padrão: Não fazer nada.

```js
function init() {
  var botao = document.getElementById("addButton");
  botao.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

function handleButtonClick() {
  var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
  var songName = textInput.value;
  if (songName == "") {
    alert("Por favor, adicione um pergunta");
  } else {
    //alert("Adicionando a música " + SongName);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = songName;
    var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}


// chamando init :)
init();
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="songTextInput" size="40" placeholder="Nome da música">
  <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Adicionar música">
</form>
<ul id="playlist">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu form falta isso para funcionar o submit

```
<form onSubmit="return false;">

</form>
```

Na tag form há um listener embutido onSubmit, quando vc coloca o botão submit, auto implementa o submit nesse botão, aí é necessário entrar com um return false para travar o submit e fazer as verificações.